# Add attribute if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add the title attribute value "not selected" if the checkbox is unchecked?

This is what I tried so far,
https://jsfiddle.net/5qakegrz/2/

```
<input type=checkbox class="fnPress" checked>1
<input type=checkbox class="fnPress">1

<script>
$(function(){
    $('input.fnPress:checked').attr("title", "selected"); 
    $('input.fnPress').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("title", "selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("title");
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: change `$(this).removeAttr("title");` to `$(this).attr("title", "not selected");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this first we can add title `not selected` on all checkboxes and then for selected one we can update it to `selected`. In `change` callback function we will add title `selected` if it is checked and if it is unchecked the title would be `not selected`. see below code.

```js
$(function(){
    $('input.fnPress').attr("title", "not selected"); 
    $('input.fnPress:checked').attr("title", "selected"); 
    $('input.fnPress').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("title", "selected");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("title", "not selected");
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<input type=checkbox class="fnPress" checked>1
<input type=checkbox class="fnPress">1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var // cache selector so we don't keep scanning the DOM over and over
    $inputs = $('input.fnPress'),
    // use a function to update the "title" attribute
    update_title = function(elements) {
      // iterate over the elements given as argument
      elements.each(function() {
        // cache the element so we save one DOM scanning
        var $this = $(this);

        // change the title attribute depending on the checkbox's state
        $this.attr(
          'title',
          $this.prop('checked') ? 'selected' : 'not selected'
        );
      });
    };

  // call the function on change
  $inputs.on('change', function() {
    update_title($inputs);
  });

  // start by setting the title attributes
  update_title($inputs);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for with detail comments. very helpful :)